# ERROR: A project with an output type of class library cannot be started directly

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, dll

I've got sample code with C#, but when I run Program I get the error message like this:

> A project with an Output type of Class Library cannot be started
> directly In order to debug this project, add an executable project to
> this solution which references the library project. Set the executable
> project as the startup project.

I'm searching in for the output . i got Answer for solving . I try that too but i m not getting any thing.

This is my Application:

[image]

Help me to get Output. What I need to do for this Error. I'm also tried to select the project to "set as startup project" but still the same error appears.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `Output type` is `Class Library`. You cannot start a class library, because it compiles to a `dll`, not an `exe`. It is intended to be used by other projects.

If you want to start that project, you should create a project of type like *Console Application*, or *WPF Application*.

Each project that can be started needs an **entry point**, for *Console Applications* this is typically a static main method in *Program.cs*, e.g.:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I change it but i got an error message like this \* "Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point" */

Comment: @Arthi try creating a class `Program` and add a `static void Main` method, just like in my example

Comment: Just make sure to select the right option when _creating_ the project.

Answer (score 2):

I once had this exact error, After I ensured that my project had the right entry point just as @Domysee rightly mentioned above...

I then resolved it just by clicking on the project name and select "Set as StartUp project" in the drop down menu.

You may be getting this error because you probably have two projects in Your solution Explorer and you need to specify which project is the start-up.